# LFO Triangle to Square wave peak distortion

Tags: wave, troubleshooting, square

I put together an LFO based off the one in the link below. I swapped out the op amps in the schematic for 741 op amps.

Everything works fine, except for the square wave. This is supposed to be the square at 1Hz.

[image: not square wave]

Frequencies above 25Hz are fine, but below that the wave becomes more like shown.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

[image]

[Link to the schematic source.](https://www.davidhaillant.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/lfo-1.4-20191103.pdf)

The LFO is currently on a breadboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> *Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?*

Set your o-scope input channel to DC.